# Using style in jquery text method

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal dialog whose content is being dynamically set in button click based on what is selected by the user. I would like to display the selection as bold. However, when rendered it displays the bold tags (less than b greater than) and (less than forward slash b greater than) instead of text being bold.

```
 JS
 $("#SubmitBtn").click(function () {
     var dropDownText = $("#DSLDropDownList option:selected").text();

     $('#ConfirmationDialog').modal('show');

     $('#ConfirmationMessage').text('You selected ' + '<b>' + dropDownText + '</b>'
 )
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 HTML
 <button type="button" id="SubmitBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

 <div id="ConfirmationDialog" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
                  <div id="ConfirmationMessage"></div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

I would like it to display, You Selected followed by value of dropDownText in bold font. Instead it displays bold tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.text()` renders given input as plaintext

Use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of `.text()`:

```
$('#ConfirmationMessage').html('You selected ' + '<b>' + dropDownText + '</b>');
```

**Example**

```js
var dropDownText = "foo";

$('#ConfirmationMessage').html('You selected ' + '<b>' + dropDownText + '</b>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<span id="ConfirmationMessage"></span>
```

Comment: Valar morghulis :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#ConfirmationMessage").html("<b>You selected " + dropDownText + " </b>");
```

Comment: No need for duplicate answers please.

Comment: don't forget the close the parenthesis

Comment: first answer won't work cause the parenthesis must close and a semicolon